# Is is better to edit the paths file or exporting PATH in .bashrc/.bash_profile?

Tags: path

I have noticed that almost every website tells you to add something like `export PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH` in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` when modifying a `PATH`.

When you want to know what your PATH is, you can `echo $PATH`, but you get this one-liner response which is kind of hard to read

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin
```

So I found out you can just `sudo vi /etc/paths` and not worry about adding anything to your bash profiles. Is this a bad method? It seems to be more clear and easier in my opinion. I guess maybe people are afraid you can mess up the `paths` and forget how to revert it back to the original state?

By the way, I'm running Mac Lion. But my question is for Linux in general.

Comment: /etc/paths is OS-X specific and not part of any Linux distro I've used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/etc/paths` does not exist on my Ubuntu system, so it may not be a GNU standard way of setting your `PATH`.

Another thing to consider is that changing `/etc/paths` will change the `PATH` of every user on the system. By putting it into your `.bash_profile`, you limit the change to one user, and only when that user uses bash as his shell.

Comment: Oh I forgot about different users. That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: GNU/Linux should check /etc/profile instead of /etc/paths... but yeah, the gist is that the shell interprets those files to look for system wide settings before it processes the users .bashrc/.profile

Comment: Side note, .bash_profile is only called when a login shell is created.